# Ошибка иморта из Eclips в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, eclipse

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0] C:\Android\AppFolder\Source\SingleWeather\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\7.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all" to force usage

Answer (score 2):

Дословно - конфликт манифестов. У либы гугло-сервисов минимальный апи - 9, а у чего-то ешё, у приложения, видимо самого - 8. Надо добавить `tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all"` или повысить уровень АПИ. Советую сразу до 16 повышать.